# How do you connect/disconnect/edit VPN connection not listed in Network Connections?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

Here's what I'm doing:

- I create a new VPN connection using `Control Panel\Network and Sharing Center`

  - `Control Panel\Network and Sharing Center`
  - `Set up a new connection or Network`
  - `Connect to a workplace`
  - `Use my Internet connection (VPN)`
- Connect to the VPN successfully
- reboot machine

After doing a reboot, I need to connect to the VPN. When I click on `Network and Sharing Center\Network Connections` the VPN connection I just created isn't displayed as an icon. When I click on the taskbar icon `Network and Sharing Center` icon the VPN connection is not listed.

**How do you connect/disconnect/edit the VPN connection when the VPN is not listed in Network Connections or taskbar?**

Answer (score 6):

**Open `rasphone` and click the Connect button and you will connect successfully to your VPN connection even though it doesn't show up in the `Network Connections`.**

---

Here is a more detailed explanation.

I found out online that Windows 7 has a less user friendly command line method for handling VPN related issues. There are two command line tools specifically:

- `rasdial` used for connecting to a VPN that is already created
- `rasphone` used for creating/editing a VPN connection

When I tried `rasphone` I found out that there were many existing VPN connections already created. Everytime I tried creating a new VPN connection there was an entry being shown in the `rasphone` listing!

`rasphone` has the following features:

- GUI pull down to list all VPN connections previously created (in my case they were all created from the `Network and Sharing Center`
- GUI button to Connect/Disconnect/shows-status
- GUI properties button
- GUI new button
- Screenshot [image]

**Solution**:

- To **connect/disconnect**: open `rasphone` click the connect/disconnect button
- To **edit the VPN connection**: open `rasphone` click the Properties button
- To **delete a VPN connection** is a little more tricky

  - each VPN connection is stored in a text file with extension *.pbk
  - there are two *.pbk files that `rasphone` looks at when you open it
  - user's *.pbk file located at: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk`
  - system *.pbk file located at: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk`
  - In my case there were many redundant VPN connections so I edited the *.pbk file and deleted the redundant VPN connections in both files
  - I left only the most recent VPN connection that I had successfully connected to
  - you can edit the *.pbk file manually however I wouldn't recommend it unless you are intimately familiar with what is valid/invalid edits to the key/value pairs and so if you aren't an expert you may break what you are trying to edit

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. In my case, I was using Windows 10 Enterprise edition, and its UI and/or whatever it triggered, had issues; 1) If I was connected, after left-clicking on the connection, expected buttons to appear (including "Disconnect"), actually no buttons appear 2) If I was disconnected and I tried to connect, I got error code 691, which is something like " Access denied because username and/or password is invalid on the domain.". When I used `rasphone` to connect, it prompted me for a username and password (and a domain!), and once I entered those, it connected successfully. Thanks again!

Comment: Even after connecting via `rasphone` the first time, and hoping the Windows 10 UI (i.e. Settings > VPN) will work subsequent attempts. I was wrong; Windows 10 UI doesn't work after that; fails for yet another reason. `rasphone` continues to work fine. Long live `rasphone` I guess!